# How can i use "leaky_relu" as an activation in Tensorflow "tf.layers.dense"?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using Tensorflow 1.5, I am trying to add `leaky_relu` activation to the output of a dense layer while I am able to change the `alpha` of `leaky_relu` (check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/leaky_relu)). I know I can do it as follows:

```
output = tf.layers.dense(input, n_units)
output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output, alpha=0.01)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to write this in one line as we can do for `relu`:

`ouput = tf.layers.dense(input, n_units, activation=tf.nn.relu)`

I tried the following but I get an error:

```
output = tf.layers.dense(input, n_units, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu(alpha=0.01))
TypeError: leaky_relu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'features'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're really adamant about a one liner for this, you could use the `partial()` method from the `functools` module, as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import partial

output = tf.layers.dense(input, n_units, activation=partial(tf.nn.leaky_relu, alpha=0.01))
```

It should be noted that `partial()` does not work for all operations and you might have to try your luck with `partialmethod()` from the same module.

Hope this helps you in your endeavour.

Comment: If you are facing `ValueError: Unknown activation function: leaky_relu` during prediction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365352/6907424
`

Answer (score 14):

At least on TensorFlow of version 2.3.0.dev20200515, [`LeakyReLU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LeakyReLU) activation with arbitrary `alpha` parameter can be used as an `activation` parameter of the [`Dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) layers:

```
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_units, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(x)
```

`LeakyReLU` activation works as:

[LeakyReLU math expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7jrp.png)

[LeakyReLU graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjn0t.png)

More information: [Wikipedia - Rectifier (neural networks)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks))

Comment: An answer that works is helpful, but consider adding an explanation to what this does.

Comment: @SovietFrontier Thank you for the comment. I just added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Note that the Keras documentation explicitly advices against this
https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/#about-advanced-activation-layers

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to do partial evaluation, and the easiest way for you to do this is to define a new function and use it

```
def my_leaky_relu(x):
    return tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.01)
```

and then you can run

```
output = tf.layers.dense(input, n_units, activation=my_leaky_relu)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do something similar in tensorflow 2.0 and I used lambda notation, as in

```
output = tf.layers.dense(input, n_units, activation=lambda x : tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.01))
```

Could be a good way to fit it all in one line.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
 
output = tf.layers.dense(input, n_units, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
```