# keras.load_model() can't recognize Tensorflow's activation functions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I saved a tf.keras model using `tf.keras.save_model` functions.
why `tf.keras.load_model` throws an exception?

code example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
])

tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    'model'
)

tf.keras.models.load_model('model')
```

I expect this code to load the model, but it throws an exception:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function:leaky_relu
```

Comment: @Sharky this is the full code. see colab example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sD2nD9dqnh3rqMfgHFZ7dPI6m6dqGtU_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add custom objects

```
tf.keras.models.load_model('model', custom_objects={'leaky_relu': tf.nn.leaky_relu})
```